# How to solve the issue "sku needs to be under 64 symbols"?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm receiving this error message below, my SKU has more than 64 symbols, but why does it happening?

[image: sku needs to be under 64 symbols]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 created this attribute using the **size 64**, you can create a module to change this column in the table **catalog_product_entity**.

[image: Magento 2 sku attribute size 64]

You can create a module like that:

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/Plugin/Ui/DataProvider/CatalogEavValidationRulesPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Rafaelcg\IncreaseSkuSize\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules;
use Rafaelcg\IncreaseSkuSize\Setup\UpgradeSchema;

class CatalogEavValidationRulesPlugin
{

    public function beforeBuild(
        CatalogEavValidationRules $subject,
        ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
        array $data
    ) {

        if ($attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel() === 'SKU') {
            $frontendClass = $attribute->getFrontendClass();
            preg_match('/maximum-length-(\d+)/', $frontendClass, $matches);
            $frontendClass = str_replace($matches[1], UpgradeSchema::NEW_SKU_LENGTH, $frontendClass);
            $attribute->setFrontendClass($frontendClass);
        }
        return [$attribute, $data];
    }

}
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Rafaelcg\IncreaseSkuSize\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    const NEW_SKU_LENGTH = 255;

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
                $setup->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_entity'),
                    'sku',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length' => self::NEW_SKU_LENGTH,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'comment' => 'SKU',
                    ]
                );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Rafaelcg_IncreaseSkuSize',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <flat>
                    <max_index_count>255</max_index_count>
                </flat>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </default>
</config>
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="rafaelcgIncreaseSkuSizeCatalogEavValidationRules" type="Rafaelcg\IncreaseSkuSize\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRulesPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Rafaelcg/IncreaseSkuSize/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rafaelcg_IncreaseSkuSize" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```